# Show confirmation box in dhtmlx scheduler onbeforeviewchange

Tags: scheduler, dhtmlx

I want to show the confirmation box before view change. So when user change date for scheduler I want to show confirmation box whether user want to redirect to another date or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use `window.confirm`

It pauses code execution until user choses any option, so you can use simple `if-else` statement:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeViewChange", function (oldMode, oldDate, mode, date) {
    if (oldMode && oldDate) {
        if (oldMode !== mode || oldDate.valueOf() !== date.valueOf()) {
            if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

demo: https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/140d2ff31

If you want a custom confirmation popup, which doesn't block the browser, you'll need to do a small workaround, since scheduler API doesn't support async event handlers:

1) when code enters onBeforeViewChange, you display the dialog and always return `false` from the handler in order to keep the same date

2) when the user confirms view change - you set some flag to temporary disable step 1 and call `scheduler.setCurrentView` from the callback. onBeforeViewChange runs again, you check the flag you've set and return `true` this time, allowing date change.

```
var callbackViewChange = false;
scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeViewChange", function (oldMode, oldDate, mode, date) {
    if (oldMode && oldDate) {
        // 
        if (!callbackViewChange && (oldMode !== mode || oldDate.valueOf() !== date.valueOf())) {
            dhtmlx.confirm({
                text: "are you sure?",
                callback: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        // set the flag in order to allow view change
                        callbackViewChange = true;
                        scheduler.setCurrentView(date, mode);
                        callbackViewChange = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            // cancel view change while we wait for user action
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

demo: https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/a2b8b09b9